# AttributeError: module 'azure.mgmt.storage.v2022_09_01.models' has no attribute 'CorsRuleAllowedMethodsItem' in azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-storage-account

I am trying to use

```
az storage fs directory download --recursive -s path/to/my/file/myfile.parquet 
   --account-name my-account-name --f my-storage-acct -d local-directory
```

I have just logged in [again] using `az login` and that was successful.  This had been working for a number of weeks - and specifically to that storage account. But now the error in the title happens.  Also the output includes the following:

```
Skip querying account key due to failure: Storage account 'saddexdatamsftdevppe' not found.
INFO: cli.azure.cli.command_modules.storage._validators: Cannot generate sas token.
     self.account_key should not be None
```

The storage account and the file both exist: I am looking at it on the Azure Portal.

Comment: Hi @WestCoastProjects have you tried with --account key "Your-acccount-key" command?

Comment: @Venkatesan I'm not sure how to find/know what is the `account-key`. I had not needed to specify it in the past. The auto-generated `~/.azure/msal_token_cache.json` has something called `account_id` but not sure if it's related.  This is a corporate account, is it related to a service principal?

Comment: Can you give brief explanation how you generating  ~/.azure/msal_token_cache.json  and authentication process with storage account ?

Comment: It's mentioned in my comment "auto-generated": it is created [I believe] by `az login`

Answer (score 0):

> Skip querying account key due to failure: Storage account 'saddexdatamsftdevppe' not found. INFO: cli.azure.cli.command_modules.storage._validators: Cannot generate sas token. self.account_key should not be None

The above error tells us that the storage account you are trying to access does not exist and it cannot generate an SAS token.

I suggest you use the **`--account-key`** parameter in your command to download the files from the from storage directory to the destination directory.

You can get the Account  key from the portal:

***Storageaccount -> Access key -> Copy the key***

[image]

**Command:**

```
az storage fs directory download --recursive -s path/to/my/file/myfile.parquet  --account-name my-account-name --f my-storage-acct -d local-directory --account-key "paste the account key here"
```

I tried the above command and it executed successfully by downloading a sample CSV file from Azure storage to the local directory.

**Output:**
[image]

**File:**

[image]

Also, you can refer to this [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/17176) issue.

**Reference:**
[az storage fs directory | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/directory?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-fs-directory-download())